# Is it possible to view PHP content that is not echoed?

Tags: php, security

Imagine the following PHP file:

```
<?php
  $topSecret = "Something important";
?>
```

If I put this on a server running the standard LAMP setup, how could someone could find out `$topSecret`?

If the variable is not echoed, is it vulnerable? A real application of this might be database credentials stored in the web root of a server.

Comment: Is today PHP security day? :) A very similar question was asked 15 mins ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287903/safest-place-to-store-php-values-for-msql-connect/2287909#2287909 and I'm about to ask one in the same vein, too. Ah, SO and its 100000s of users...

Comment: Yeah, that question prompted me to ask this one. Thought it would be better to create a new question rather than ask one in a comments thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If PHP were to fail somhow, then the page would be displayed as a plaint text file. That has happened before; it once happened to [Facebook](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/facebook-source-code.html). To protect against this you should store all sensitive variables (passwords, etc) in a php file which is not in the web root. You could store it in the parent folder (if you have access to it) or in a subfolder which is protected by apache (`deny all`).

Answer (score 6):

Under normal circumstances, it would not be possible to view that.

But errors in configuration, or exploits in code could make it possible to view the contents of the files.

Normally, one would place such information outside of the webroot, to decrease the chance such a thing happens.